# monacaで作ったiOSアプリがプッシュ通知APIを使用していると警告される

Tags: monaca

monacaを用いてiosアプリを初めて開発しました。
Appleに審査してもらう為に「Application Loader」を使用してUpLoadしたところ、
プログラム内にプッシュ通知のAPIを使用しているがプロビジョニングでは許可されていないといった警告が返ってくるので、このまま進めても審査に通るのか不安です。
警告文曰く、プッシュ通知を使用していないなら、
・プログラム内からプッシュ通知のロジックを除去する。
・もし、サードパーティーを使用しているなら開発者に連絡する。
と書かれています。

私はプッシュ通知のロジックは組み込んでいないのですがmonacaが標準で組み込んでいるのでしょうか？
試しにmonacaの初期プロジェクトで入っている「Hello World」をそのままビルドしてUpLoadしても同じ警告が返ってきます。
プッシュ通知のロジックを組めば解決すると思いますが、今のところプッシュ通知を使用しないのでできればプッシュ通知を組み込まずにリリースしたいと思っています。
プッシュ通知を組み込まずに解決する方法があればよろしくお願いします。
（この警告が出ても審査が通るのでしたら問題ありません）

monacaで作ったiOSアプリをAppleStoreへ登録する基本的なこととは思いますよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 自己レスです。
monaca標準で組み込まれるloader.jsを見ると「Push Notification」の記述があるようなので、とりあえずプッシュ通知を組み込むことにより回避させました。

Comment: 確認ですが、設定画面の「Cordovaプラグイン管理」で、MonacaPushNotificationsは無効になっていますよね？